# Rspec error: Expected at least 1 element matching "form[action="/clients/1"][method="post"]", found 0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, minitest

Noob here,
Let me start from what and why I did:
There is a User model which is used by client and caregiver (who are users with different role ). I did scaffold to generate client and caregiver with --skip-migration and then deleted the auto generated model (Client.rb and Caregiver.rb) and replaced Client with User in the generated controllers and views.

Everything seems to work fine but I think that only seemed. While I was testing the views, I get the error below:

```
 Minitest::Assertion:
       Expected at least 1 element matching "form[action="/clients/1"][method="post"]", found 0..
       Expected 0 to be >= 1.
```

Here are the contents of other related files:

controllers/clients_controller

```
class ClientsController < ApplicationController

  # GET /clients/1/edit
  def edit
  end
end
```

spec/views/clients/edit_spec

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe "clients/edit", type: :view do
  before(:each) do
      @client = FactoryGirl.create :client_user   
  end

  it "renders the edit client form" do
    render

    assert_select "form[action=?][method=?]", client_path(@client), "post" do
    end
  end
end
```

views/clients/edit.html.haml

```
%h1 Editing client

= render 'form'

= link_to 'Show', @client
\|
= link_to 'Back', clients_path
```

views/clients/_form.html.haml

```
= form_for @client do |f|
  - if @client.errors.any?
    #error_explanation
      %h2= "#{pluralize(@client.errors.count, "error")} prohibited this client from being saved:"
      %ul
        - @client.errors.full_messages.each do |msg|
          %li= msg

  .actions
    = f.submit 'Save'
```

Did I miss anything while deleting existing models ? Or How should I do ? One model and multiple controllers. 
If any other files required ?

P.S - I haven't touched the views generated by rails.

Comment: Please provide the [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Just spitting out the whole repository looks like a request to rewrite the code for you.

Comment: @mudasobwa What exactly should i add here ? Scaffolding client and using User model instead of Client model reproduces it. Other are auto generated by rails generate scaffold Client.

Comment: You should remove 90% of the above to provide the MCVE.

Comment: I wanted to know if I missed something after scaffold and deleting the model because, I think that's where the thing went wrong. Sorry that, it looked like that. I have updated now.

Comment: Thanks for understanding. Now please get rid of the factory, since it worked fine (since `client_path(@client)` returned `/clients/1`,) and share the part of view that is being tested.

Comment: When you open the form in the browser, are you sure the method for submit is `post`? According to http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html it is `patch/put` (I am not a rails guru, sorry for that, just a wild guess.)

Comment: I don' think, that's the issue because test passes for freshly scaffolded views. (without deleting model)

Answer (score 0):

Interesting thing is that you are writing your specs with rspec, while having errors from minitest, never did that kind of combination before, but are you sure you are running proper tests? With rspec you should run your tests with `bundle exec rspec`

Second thing, you need to assign this object that was created by FactoryGirl to instance variable in your view

require 'rails_helper'

```
describe 'clients/edit' do
  let(:client) { FactoryGirl.create(:client_user) } # Prefer using let instead of before each, why? in case you make typo in `@client` you are going to get "nil" error, if you are going to make typo in `client` you are going to get Unknown Attribute/Method error. There are more advantages to it you can read about this in rspec documentation at https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs

  before do # before and before(:each) are basically the same
    assign(:client, client) # now you need to assign instance variable in view so those are the same when you are doing the assertion below
    render # render the view
  end

  it 'renders the edit client form' do
    render

    assert_select "form[action=?][method=?]", client_path(client), "post" do


    end

    # Rspec way
    expect(rendered).to have_css('css selector goes here')
  end
end
```

And, btw, you do not need an empty method `edit` in your controller, rails looks up for view files, so if there is edit.* file in your folder then it will work without this ugly empty method.

Comment: Hey @mswiszcz, thanks for your reply. Any ways I had to user_path instead of client_path.

`assert_select "form[action=?][method=?]", user_path(client), "post" do`

I needed /users/1/ instead of /clients/1. Found out using inspect element.